# How to collect array objects' values to separate the array in MongoDB Aggregation Framework?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

Here is the example of collection content:

*bloggers*

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId(...),
        posts: [
            {
                "platform": "instagram"
            },
            {
                "platform": "tiktok"
            },
        ],
        full_name: "John Doe",
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(...),
        posts: [
            {
                "platform": "youtube"
            },
            {
                "platform": "tiktok"
            },
        ],
        full_name: "Mamed Mamedov"
    }
]
```

And as a result of the aggregation, I wanna get something like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId(...),
        platforms: ["instagram", "tiktok"],
        full_name: "John Doe",
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId(...),
        platforms: ["youtube", "tiktok],
        full_name: "Mamed Mamedov"
    }
]
```

(List of the platforms from `posts` field)

For now, I even not sure, that there is some ready-to-use method in mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easy with $reduce:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$project": {
  "full_name":1,
  "platforms": {
    "$reduce": {
      "input": "$posts",
      "initialValue": [],
      in: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$$value",
          [
            "$$this.platform"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
])
```

[example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b9AztSx-fs-)